# About Computational complexity of a residual network

Tags: deep-learning, resnet, deep-residual-networks

While training a residual network, doesn't the residual layer increases the computational complexity of the network with so many weights to train in the residual block?

Comment: Yes, it does, but a residual layer does not add any weights.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't add any weights?

Comment: Exactly that, the residual connection does not have weights or adds any weights to the model.